# JSON parsing error with axios (unexpected character in server response)

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios

I'm getting a JSON parsing error when I try to fetch data from a server endpoint.

It's the first time that Axios cannot decode the JSON response automatically.

Debugging my code, I've seen that Axios catch some unexpected character in the server response that makes the JSON not valid.

```
7F5
{
  "message": "OK"
  ...cut
}
0
```

Error:

```
(node:14940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token F in JSON at position 1
```

I suppose that could be a charset encoding problem.

Axios client configuration:

```js
const pclClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://server/endpoint",
  responseType: "json",
  responseEncoding: "utf8",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    charset: "utf-8"
  }
});
```

Using tools like postman or Chrome Extension Advanced Request Client, the problem is not present.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try remove `responseEncoding `, `charset `

Comment: Your message beginning with `7F5` isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @haongdv. Removed but I've always the problem. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: @O.Jones I know. This is the problem that I've. The response contains the 7F5 character returned from the webserver. I cannot change this issue.

Comment: That looks like chunked HTTP, except that the content is not 2037 (0x7F5) bytes long. The details of chunked HTTP should normally by handled by the HTTP client.

Comment: Thank you, @rveerd. You are right. I've trunked the response without specifying it. I'm using `axios`, and it seems that I've incurred in this issue https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1768. I'm considering to split the response with `\r\n` string to exclude chunk data ad parse only the JSON string. But I don't know if it could be the right approach.

Comment: Interesting thread here.  Please do take the time to write an "Answer" when you've solved it.

Comment: @MikeRobinson. I've found a workaround using regex to parse chunks and remove unexpected characters before parsing the JSON response. I've posted the answer with the details. Thank you for our comment.

Answer (score 4):

The problem comes from `transfer-encoding: chunked` response header.

[RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-4.1) tells that "A recipient MUST be able to parse and decode the chunked transfer
coding."

At the moment, **Axios** don't handle chunked responses ([transfer-encoding chunked not handled for application/json](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1768))

To resolve this issue, I've made a chunk parser using regex to removing chunk's info.

```js
const pclClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://server/",
  responseType: "json",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json"
  }
});

const chunksParser = body => {
  return body
    .replace(/^(\w{1,3})\r\n/, "") // replace header chunks info 
    .replace(/\r\n(\w{1,3})\r\n/, "") // replace in-body chunks info
    .replace(/(\r\n0\r\n\r\n)$/, ""); // replace end chunks info
};

const getData = async () => {
  response = await pclClient.get("data.json");
  const { data } = response;
  const body = chunksParser(data);
  const json = JSON.parse(body);
  return json;
};
```

I was looking for a built-in function inside Axios. I hope it will be available in the future.

Thank you for commenters that helped me to understand what was the problem.